# How to set environment variable for non-root user with docker-compose?

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

This one works (set `PERL5LIB` for user `root`):

```
test:
        image: httpd
        environment:
            - PERL5LIB=/somedir
        command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
                perl -le 'print for @INC'
```

This one too (set `PERL5LIB` for user `daemon`):

```
test:
        image: httpd
        user: daemon
        environment:
            - PERL5LIB=/somedir
        command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
                perl -le 'print for @INC'
```

(launch `command:` from `daemon` user)

But problem appears when I start foreground process in docker container from `root` user but process launch from non-root user. E.g. `httpd` can't launch from root, default user for `httpd-foreground` is `daemon`.

I tried to set `PERL5LIB` globally, using `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment` but neither option worked:

```
services:
    test:
        image: httpd
        command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
                echo 'export PERL5LIB=/somedir' >> /etc/profile
                perl -le 'print for @INC'
```

```
services:
    test2:
        image: httpd
        command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
                echo 'PERL5LIB="/somedir"' >> /etc/environment
                perl -le 'print for @INC'
```

( no `/somedir` in output )

How to set `PERL5LIB` for `daemon` user without launching `command:` from `daemon` user ?

Comment: Can you explain how you’re launching the container/process?  Usually these two things aren’t separable: the lifecycle of the main container process is exactly the lifecycle of the process.

Comment: Also note that a string `command:` is automatically wrapped in `sh -c` (you don’t need to run that explicitly) and that most shell dotfiles (including `/etc/environment`) don’t get read at all in a typical Docker flow.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I launch container by simple `docker-compose up`. Is there any alternative way to `/etc/environment` ? Or maybe we can force to read `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` ?

Comment: The `docker-compose.yml` `environment:` setting you have here should be correct.  Or since it looks like you’re trying to set a path for installed software, you could use an `ENV` directive in your `Dockerfile`, or just run the system CPAN to install into the default directory tree.  What problem are you encountering?

Comment: 1) I have no access to `Dockerfile`, prefer not to build intermediate images so can set `ENV` only via `docker-compose` 2) I need to mount as volume script with it's own libraries that are not on CPAN so I need to set `PERL5LIB` to this volume path.